# HttpLib2 throws error when trying to do a request to couchdb

Tags: python, couchdb, httplib2

I'm building an application in Python2.6 that needs to get data from CouchDb. I'm using [CouchDB-0.8-py2.6](http://code.google.com/p/couchdb-python/) to connect to the database.
I'm using this code:

```
import couchdb
server = couchdb.Server(url='http://localhost:5984/', full_commit=True, session=None)
db = server['databaseName']
doc = db['docId']
value = doc['value']
print(value)
```

On my local machine (OSX) the code runs perfectly, but when I'm trying to run it on a Debian server, I get the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/CouchDB-0.7dev_r199-py2.6.egg/couchdb/client.py", line 165, in __getitem__
   db.resource.head() # actually make a request to the database
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/CouchDB-0.7dev_r199-py2.6.egg/couchdb/client.py", line 977, in head
   return self._request('HEAD', path, headers=headers, **params)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/CouchDB-0.7dev_r199-py2.6.egg/couchdb/client.py", line 1010, in _request
   resp, data = _make_request()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/CouchDB-0.7dev_r199-py2.6.egg/couchdb/client.py", line 1005, in _make_request
   body=body, headers=headers)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/httplib2-0.6.0-py2.6.egg/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1025, in request
   cached_value = self.cache.get(cachekey)
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I've tried to Google this numerous times and no-one seems to have the same error. Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: which line of your code causes this error?

Comment: this one: db = server['databaseName']

Comment: Which versions of Httplib and Python are you using on server/local machine?

Comment: @jsalonen: the traceback answers your question, doesn't it?

Comment: Local: Python 2.6.1 and Httplib2 version I don't know, on the server it's in the stacktrace and Python 2.6.6

Comment: @SilentGhost yes, good point, but the specific versions from the local machine are missing. What I'm after here is that what is the difference in the configuration that leads to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a different version of CouchDB on the server - CouchDB-0.7dev_r199. CouchDB does not use httplib2 anymore, so if you get your development and server environments roughly the same the problem is quite likely to disappear.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll have to look into that. We had a lot of problems installing the python-couchdb lib on the server. We eventually checked it out from the repo, but that one appears to be an old version...